# Scheduled Function: HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run a firebase function everyday at midnight.

```
export const validatePremium = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *').onRun(async context => {

    const snaps = await admin.firestore().collection("Users").where("premium", "==", true).get();

    // SOME BUSINESS LOGIC
    return true;
})
```

I get the error

```
⚠  functions: failed to create function validatePremium
HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors
```

Which is not very helpful.

If I run the same code as a `https.onCall` function, it works.

What can be the problem?

Comment: If you're having problems deploying functions that don't have a meaningful error message, please contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 2):

Updating firebase-tools fixed to issue